# Java Using Comparators in combination with custom Comparators

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

I want to sort the following example list which currently contains only Strings with my own custom rules.

```
ArrayList<String> coll = new ArrayList<>();
coll.add("just");
coll.add("sdsd");
coll.add("asb");
coll.add("b as");
coll.add("just");
coll.add("dhfga");
coll.add("jusht");
coll.add("ktsa");
coll.add("just");
coll.add("just");
```

I know that I could write my own comparator for this, but as I know that Java also got comparators which solve this problem partially I want to know how I can use the ones from the Java API **in combination** with my own one.

---

### How should it be sorted?

The word `just` should always be the first word to appear in the list followed by all other words in alphabetical order.

`Comparator.naturalOrder()` sorts the list in alphabetical order, but how can I combine this comperator with a custom one which checks whether the word is `just` or something else.

Comment: Do you want to exclude repeated "just" word or not?

Comment: I don't want to exclude them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this something like that:

```
coll.sort(Comparator
    .comparingInt((String s) -> s.equals("just") ? 0 : 1) // Words "just" first
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())); // Then others
```

Comment: `Boolean` is `Comparable`, so there is no need to deal with `int` values here: `coll.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("just")) .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`

Comment: @Holger Right. Or even shorter: `coll.sort(null); coll.sort(Comparator.comparing("just"::equals).reversed());`

Comment: Yes, the sort operation is stable and `null` means “natural order”, but I’d avoid exploiting this; performing two sort operations might not be very efficient and using `null` as comparator undermines the generic type system, as you won’t have a compile-time check whether the elements are actually comparable. So I’d stay with the compound comparator with a single `sort`. Or do the “move `"just"` to front” without sorting like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50484556/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger The `null` part can be fixed with `Collections.sort(coll)`.

Comment: Or you stay with `coll.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate the criteria into the comparator like

```
coll.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("just"))
                    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

or you separate the operations, first moving all occurrences of `"just"` to the front, then sorting the remaining elements only:

```
int howManyJust = 0;
for(int ix = 0, num = coll.size(); ix < num; ix++)
    if(coll.get(ix).equals("just") && ++howManyJust <= ix)
        Collections.swap(coll, ix, howManyJust-1);

coll.subList(howManyJust, coll.size()).sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

while this may look more complicated, it is potentially more efficient, especially for larger lists.

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be to define the custom order. I would do that by using a Map.

```
Map<String, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
int order = 0;
for(String specialWord : yourListOfSpecialWords){
    orderMap.put(specialWord, order++);
}
```

Now build comparator using that map and natural order as backup:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = ((Comparator<String>) (o1, o2) -> {
    int leftScore = orderMap.getOrDefault(o1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    int rightScore = orderMap.getOrDefault(o2, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return Integer.compare(leftScore, rightScore);
}).thenComparing(String::compareTo);
```

Use this comparator to sort your list. Note: you probably want to initialize your map only once and keep it in a constant or at least in a cache.

But if your special case is only a single word, as your update suggests, then this is of course overkill, and you should go with one of the other answers here.

Comment: You can avoid the code duplication by using `Comparator.comparingInt((String o) -> orderMap.getOrDefault(o, Integer.MAX_VALUE))`. Further, you don’t need the `int order` variable when you simply use `orderMap.put(specialWord, orderMap.size());`.